# Simple Question About Partition of Interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Something seems to be messing me up with a seemingly very simple calculation.

say I have some interval $[a,b)$, and I'm given some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and I want to find a restriction on $jr$, $r$ a fixed integer and $j$ a natural number allowed to vary, so that I can partition the interval in such a way that, for some $k$,

1. $b-\frac{1}{n} < a + \frac{k}{jr} < b$ 
   and
2. $b-(a+\frac{k}{jr}) > \frac{1}{4n}$

it's easy to satisfy the first condition, just take say $jr>4n$. Though I'm not sure how to restrict the size of $jr$ so that the second property also holds. This question arose as a lemma to show that we may approximate the length of an interval $A$ by the value $$\#(A \cap \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{N})\frac{1}{N}$$
namely that the length is the limit of such values as $N$ increases. Indeed I've tried to approximate an interval $A$ by the 'right' type of compact intervals from inside (i.e. ones so that the discrete cardinality value is exactly the length of the compact interval for each $N$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given the three marks $$b-{1\over n}<b-{1\over 4n}<b$$
on the number line, and a lattice $\Lambda=\{a+k\delta\>|\>k\in{\mathbb Z}\}$, whereby you have some control over the lattice width $\delta>0$. In particular there are arbitrary small widths $\delta$ available. It is then obvious that there will be a lattice point between the first two marks as soon as $\delta<{3\over 4n}$.

Comment: thank you. I'm not sure why this was messing me up so, I knew it was true, just not how to prove that such a point exists by writing it explicitly. though, for the proof of the overall statement, I only need existence of such a point. so you say $jr>\frac{4n}{3}$ will suffice?